# How can I sum across the rows of a dataset?

Tags: sas

I'd like the sum of the rows of a data set.  In particular, I would like to sum from the second element to the last element (skipping the first entry).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried?  What is your data like?  This is a wholly trivial task in SAS a number of ways even for a beginner, so we need to know a) that you've made some effort to solve it and b) what issues you're running into so our solutions can be best tailored to your needs.

Comment: Data is entirely integers, but the first column is an integer ID number.  I dont wan't to include that in the sum.  Solutions I have sen so far use proc data and just create a new column by summing the rows individually. I'm writing a script that will be used over time, and so the number of columns may change from use to use.  For this reason, the proc data solution is not appropriate.

Comment: what is `proc data`???  You need more details.  Example and what you have tried.  You have not explained any difficulty so far that should stop a first-month-SAS programmer from solving this, so you need to put that, in the question, why this is a question.  Example data.  Example of what you want.  Not in comments, but in the question. I think it is still unclear what you even mean by "first entry" and "across the rows"...

Comment: @Joe its ok, looks like Otto understood what I needed.  Thanks

Comment: @DemetriP If you find the answer useful, it is customary to upvote it and/or mark it as the accepted answer if it solves your problem.  If it doesn't solve your problem, please provide more info so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to add up everything except the first column.  You also don't know how many variables you have and it many change over time.

There may be a smarter way to do this, but here are 3 options.

If your ID value is stored as text while everything else is a number, then it is trivial to say:

```
data sum;
  set test;
  sum =  sum(of _numeric_);
run;
```

which will simply add up all numeric variables.  However it sounds like you have integer IDs, so perhaps one of these options would work.  First, some sample data:

```
data test;
  input id var1 var2 var3;
cards;
1 2 2 2
2 3 3 3
3 4 4 4
4 5 5 5
;
run;
```

Option 1 - Simply add up all of the numeric variables, and then subtract your ID value, this leaves you with the sum of everything except the ID:

```
data test2;
  set test;
  sum=sum(of _numeric_)-id;
run;
```

Option 2 - You can tell SAS to operate over a range of variables in the order they are listed in the dataset.  You could just do `sum = sum(var1--var3);`, however you might not know what the first and last variables are.  There's also a possibility that your ID variable is in the middle somewhere.

A solution to this would be to make sure your ID variable is first, and then create dummy variables before and after the range of variables you want to sum:

```
data test3;
  format id START_SUM;
  set test;
  END_SUM = .;
  sum = sum(of START_SUM--END_SUM);
  drop START_SUM END_SUM;
run;
```

This creates ID and START_SUM before setting your data, and then creates the empty END_SUM at the end of your data.  It then sums everything from START_SUM to END_SUM, and because `sum(of ...)` skips over missing values, you only get the sum of the variables you actually care about.  Then you drop your dummy variables as they are no longer necessary.

Option 1 is obviously simpler, but Option 2 has some potential benefits in that it works with both numeric and non-numeric IDs, and has no chance of being subject to any sorts of weird rounding issues when you add and subtract the ID (although that won't happen if everything is an integer).